# Ruby on Rails - No route matches [POST] "/setor/update"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

i'm new to ruby on rails and I keep getting this error when trying to update an object.
here's my controller:

```
class SetorController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @setor = Setor.all
  end

  def new

  end

  def show
      @setor = Setor.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @setor = Setor.new(setor_params)
    @setor.save
    redirect_to @setor
  end

  def edit
    @setor = Setor.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
    @setor = Setor.find(params[:id])
    if (@setor.update(setor_params))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private def setor_params
    params.require(:setor).permit(:nome, :sigla, :cnpj)
  end
end
```

this is the index page - where I link to edit the object:

```
<%= @setor.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.nome %> |
  <%= s.sigla %> |
  <%= s.cnpj %> |
  <%= link_to "edit", edit_setor_path(s.id) %> <br>

<% end %>
```

and this is the update form:

```
<h1> Editar Setor </h1>

<%= form_for :setor, url: setor_path(:update) do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :nome %>
  <%= f.text_field :nome %> <br>
  <%= f.label :sigla %>
  <%= f.text_field :sigla %> <br>
  <%= f.label :cnpj %>
  <%= f.text_field :cnpj %> <br>
</p>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have a route that matches `edit_setor_path`. You can do this by running `rails routes` in your terminal or by going to the url `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` in your browser.

On your index page, you have the following:

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_setor_path(s.id) %> <br>
```

You do not need to pass in the id of the s object. Rails will figure this out on its own. Instead, just pass in the object:

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_setor_path(s) %> <br>
```

Change `@setor` in the index action of your SetorController to `@setors` and change `@setor` in your index.html.erb file to `@setors`.

Change the :sector in your edit.html.erb to @setor. You can also remove `url: setor_path(:update)` from the edit.html.erb form.

These changes follow Rails conventions. You should try to follow Rails conventions as much as possible, especially when just learning Rails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, making the changes seemed to solve the problem. How does rails know that when I submit a form, the method it needs to call is create or update?

Comment: form_for calls the .new_record? method on the passed in object. If .new_record? returns false, Rails knows the record exists in the database and runs the edit action of the controller. If .new_record? returns true, Rails knows the object doesn't yet exist and runs the new action of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mention `@setor` object in the form code:

```
<%= form_for @setor do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like this:

Rename your controller to `setors_controller.rb` and change the class name to `SetorsController` -- this is to follow the typical Rails naming convention.

Then make sure you have a route:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :setors
end
```

Update your view's `form_for` tag to use the instance variable set up in the controller:

```
# app/views/setors/edit.html.erb
# NOTE: folder path above... "setor" is now "setors" to follow the Rails convention
<%= form_for @setor do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :nome %>
    <%= f.text_field :nome %> <br>
    <%= f.label :sigla %>
    <%= f.text_field :sigla %> <br>
    <%= f.label :cnpj %>
    <%= f.text_field :cnpj %> <br>
  </p>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: if I put `@setor` on the form_for I get this error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. Solved this problem adding `@setor = Sector.new on the "new"` method